# Twitter,"Could not authenticate you" Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter, ionic-framework, twitter-oauth

I am trying to update or post Status on Twitter in Ionic. I have done oauth using ngCordova.it is working fine to get UserProfile Api.
But when i try to post Image or status it gives error ("Could not authenticate you").
See my Code here.

```
    var services = angular.module('twitter.service', [])
    services.factory('TwitterLoginFactory', function($http, $cordovaOauthUtility, $cordovaOauth, $state) {
/*=================================================
 Twitter Local Storage Functions and Keys
=================================================*/
var twitterKey = "STORAGE.TWITTER.KEY";
var twitterUserProfile = "STORAGE.TWITTER.USER";
/** Store Twitter User Profile in Local Storage**/
function storeTwitterProfile(data) {
    window.localStorage.setItem(twitterUserProfile, JSON.stringify(data));
}
/** Get  Twitter User Profile in Local Storage**/
function getStoredTwitterProfile() {
    return window.localStorage.getItem(twitterUserProfile);
}
/** Store Twitter access_token in Local Storage**/
function storeTwitterToken(data) {
    window.localStorage.setItem(twitterKey, JSON.stringify(data));
}
/** Get Twitter access_token in Local Storage**/
function getStoredTwitterToken() {
    return window.localStorage.getItem(twitterKey);
}
/**
 * Convert an image 
 * to a base64 url
 * @param  {String}   url         
 * @param  {Function} callback    
 * @param  {String}   [outputFormat=image/png]           
 */
function convertImgToBase64URL(url, callback, outputFormat) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
            dataURL;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        callback(dataURL);
        canvas = null;
    };
    img.src = url;
}
/*=================================================
     Twitter Login and Get Profile Section
=================================================*/
return {
    login: function($scope) {
        var token = getStoredTwitterToken();
        if (token !== null) {
            $state.go('tab');
            return;
        }
        /** Twitter Api Keys **/
        var clientId = "hhskhk########";
        var clientSecret = "fhskfsks#######";
        console.log("twitterLogin function got called");
        /** Twitter Login Call **/
        $cordovaOauth.twitter(clientId, clientSecret).then(function(result) {
            //Stroe Response or Token into Local Storage
            storeTwitterToken(result);
            /** Twitter call Response in varibales **/
            var oauth_token = result.oauth_token;
            var oauth_token_secret = result.oauth_token_secret;
            var user_id = result.user_id;
            var screen_name = result.screen_name;
            /** Twitter oauth for User Details **/
            //Accessing profile info from twitter
            var oauthObject = {
                oauth_consumer_key: clientId,
                oauth_nonce: $cordovaOauthUtility.createNonce(10),
                oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
                oauth_token: result.oauth_token,
                oauth_timestamp: Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000.0),
                oauth_version: "1.0"
            };
            //var signatureObj = $cordovaOauthUtility.createSignature(method, url, oauthObject, {}, clientSecret, token.oauth_token_secret);
            var signatureObj = $cordovaOauthUtility.createSignature("GET", "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json", oauthObject, {
                screen_name: result.screen_name
            }, clientSecret, result.oauth_token_secret);
            console.log("Generating signature");
            console.log(signatureObj);
            console.log(signatureObj.signature);
            localStorage.setItem('sig', JSON.stringify(signatureObj));
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = signatureObj.authorization_header;
            $http.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json', {
                params: {
                    screen_name: screen_name
                }
            }).success(function(data) {
                console.log('Twitter UserProfile: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                //Stroe Response or Profile into Local Storage
                storeTwitterProfile(data);
                // localStorage.setItem('user', data.screen_name);
                $state.go('tab');
                // var  currentUser = data.screen_name;
                // var myString = data.profile_image_url;
                // var newString = myString.substr(0, myString.length-12);
                // var currentUserImage = newString+".jpeg";
                // window.localStorage.setItem("currentUser", currentUser);
                //  window.localStorage.setItem("currentUserImage", currentUserImage);
            })
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            // alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    },
    postTPhoto: function(obj, $scope) {
        console.log(obj);
        var status = 'test';
        var img = null;
        convertImgToBase64URL(obj.picPath, function(base64) {
            console.log(base64);
            img = base64;
        });
        // var fs = require('fs');
        // var request = require('request');
        // var FormData = require('form-data');
        // var utf8 = require('utf8');
        // Encode in UTF-8
        // status = utf8.encode(status);
        var token = JSON.parse(getStoredTwitterToken());
        var clientId = "hhskhk########";
        var clientSecret = "fhskfsks#######";
        /** Twitter oauth for User Details **/
        // Accessing profile info from twitter
        var oauthObject = {
            oauth_consumer_key: clientId,
            oauth_nonce: $cordovaOauthUtility.createNonce(10),
            oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
            oauth_token: token.oauth_token,
            oauth_timestamp: Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000.0),
            oauth_version: "1.0"
        };
        // var signatureObj = $cordovaOauthUtility.createSignature("POST", "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json", oauthObject, {
        var signatureObj = $cordovaOauthUtility.createSignature("POST", "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json", oauthObject, {
            // https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json
            // media_data: img
            // screen_name: token.screen_name
            status: "Testing Api"
        }, clientSecret, token.oauth_token_secret);
        console.log("Generating signature");
        console.log(signatureObj);
        console.log(signatureObj.signature);
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = signatureObj.authorization_header;
        // $http.post('https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json', {
        $http.post('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json', {
            params: {
                status: "Testing Api"
            }
        }).success(function(response) {
            $scope.response = response;
        }).error(function(error) {
            $scope.error = error;
        });
        // $http.post({
        //            url: 'https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json',
        //            method: 'POST',
        //            data:{media_data: img},
        //            headers: {
        //                "Content-Type": "application/json"
        //            }
        //        }).success(function(response){
        //            $scope.response = response;
        //        }).error(function(error){
        //            $scope.error = error;
        //        });
        //   $http.post('https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json', {
        //         params: {
        //             media_data: img
        //         }
        //     }).success(function(data) {
        //     })
        // }, function(error) {
        //     console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        //     // alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        // });
    },
    getStoredTwitterToken: getStoredTwitterToken,
    getStoredTwitterProfile: getStoredTwitterProfile,
    storeTwitterProfile: storeTwitterProfile,
    storeTwitterToken: storeTwitterToken,
    convertImgToBase64URL: convertImgToBase64URL
};
});
```

Answer (score -1):

find this useful link so have a look if it can solve your issue.

http://santoshshinde2012.blogspot.com/2015/03/share-images-text-messages-via-facebook.html

Comment: i dont want to use sharePlugin, i want to share with api and i am already using oauth to login.